# Multiple selected data doesn't appear

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, jquery-select2

I use [select2](https://select2.github.io/) for multiple select. My problem is, I can select multiple value from json data and I can save this data in related model columns. But when I want to update this model, the selected data doesn't appear.

some part of my json data:

```
{
 - categories:[
   - {
       id:7,
       name:"Eğitim Bilimleri Enstitüsü"
     },
   - {
       id: 8,
       name: "Eğitim Yönetim Teftişi ve Planlaması 1. Yarıyıl"
     },
   ...
  ]
}
```

I have a Moodle class(it is not inheritance from ActiveRecord, just a class and it has some functions which return json data). I am wondering whether it is right approach.

in the content of my form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@period) do |f| %>
...
    <%= f.input :moodle_connect_ids, collection: Moodle.categories.map {|p| [ p['name'], p['id'] ] }, input_html: {multiple: true} %>
...
<% end %>
```

I explicitly set moodle_connect_ids to be an array in my controller:

```
params.require(:period).permit(..., :moodle_connect_ids => [])
```

in the content of my .js file:

```
$("#period_moodle_connect_ids").select2({
  placeholder: "Moodle Dönem Bağlantılarını Seçiniz",
  multiple: true,
  allowClear: true
});
```

When I select to multiple values and save my model, the column's value looks like this:

```
> Period.last
=> #<Period:0x007fcf53a4d830
id: 25,
...
moodle_connect_ids: "[\"\", \"85\", \"120\"]" 
...
```

Am I on the wrong way? Have you any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out how to do this issue.

I've added selected option in the f.input:

```
selected: @period.moodle_connect_ids? ? JSON.parse(@period.moodle_connect_ids).map(&:to_i) : []
```

the input's last state:

```
<%= f.input :moodle_connect_ids, collection: Moodle.categories.map {|p| [ p['name'], p['id'] ] }, input_html: {multiple: true}, selected: @period.moodle_connect_ids? ? @period.moodle_connect_ids.map(&:to_i) : [] %>
```